# Javascript for showing bubbles based on percentage

Tags: javascript, css

I need a javascript for displaying the result which is returned as percentage values in the form of bubbles. The bubbles size need to be based on percentage values. If the percentage value is 20%, then the size of that bubble should be small, If 60%, size is bigger. Could someone help me with this. thanks.

Comment: We will be glad to help. Can you post the code you tried, and elaborate on the problems you're encountering with it?

Comment: "I need a javascript", "the bubbles size need", "should be" are not phrases that should be in your question. They should be things like "I've tried [this]" and "it's not working [because]" and other things that show you've put effort into your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code bellow.

```
<style>

    #circle {

        border: 1px solid red;

        border-radius: 50%;

        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;

        box-sizing: border-box;

        background:pink;
  }

</style>

<div id="circle"> </div>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(function(){

        var maxWidth = 200, // This is the max width of your circle

        percent = 0.7; // This is the percentage value

        $("#circle").css({

            "width" : maxWidth * percent,

            "height" : maxWidth * percent           
        });

    });

</script>
```

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, what IDE did you use to produce your code? I've seen the double line spacing quite a lot recently

Comment: @Bojangles I use Aptana Studio 3.

Comment: Thanks, I have to get the percent value from some div